# Nest.Js: import files from outside project folder

Tags: typescript, directory, nestjs

I started using Nest.Js and I created a Full Stack App with this structure:

[image: app structure]

`api`: nestjs app
`client`: frontend app
`models`: shared models (interfaces only) between back and front

So I set alias path in `tsconfig.json` inside api folder to let it import shortly: `import { User } from 'models/user.model'`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "incremental": true, 
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "models/*": ["../models/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that typescript is compiling and changing the root structure under `dist` folder and nest cli is not finding `main.js` file to start up the application.

[image: dist folder]

Is there a way to move `models` folder and preserve nestjs structure?
Or maybe change nestjs config to start the app on `api/src/main.js`?

Comment: Hi can you tell me what icon package you're using please? :-)

Comment: @RyanWeiss `Material Icon Theme` for vscode

Comment: Thanks @Eduardo!

Comment: @EduardoRosostolato Did you get an error when building production export? cuz `paths` was not working with production build

Comment: @SayJeyHi I didn't move forward with this project and I haven't tried it on production, so I can't say it... Sorry.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is something typescript does when there is code outside of the root `src` directory, to make sure that after compilation the same paths can be used. You can modify the `nest-cli.json` and add an `entryFile` property to tell Nest where the `main` file is. Also, consider something like [`Nx`](https://nx.dev) to help with creating fullstack monorepos.

Comment: Perfect! I set `"entryFile": "api/src/main"` on `nest-cli.json` and it worked! Thank you!

Comment: Brilliant! That's what I'm looking for! (after searching and trying a lot like a headless fly...)

Comment: Just a note that I had to also delete the `dist` folder to get this to update properly with `paths`

Comment: Can you instead tell Typescript not to do that ? I have the same issue, but in my folder I have an Angular application alongside the Nest app, and the issue does not happen with Angular, only with Nest ... (And yes, I use the file in both projects)

Comment: Angular uses webpack, which will output a singe file that's a bundle of your application. You can do the same with Nest, that's actually how Nx sets up monorepo workspaces for the most part